# Layered Navigation in magento is not working with Configurable products

Tags: magento, configurable-product, layered-navigation

I am using this extension in my magento web store
http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus (Layered navigation)
This extension working fine for simple products.

But in my case, I have two attributes that would be used to create configurable products, i.e Size and Color. Now when I create my configurable products, and associate my simple products of different sizes and colors to that configurable product and browse the Category Landing page, In layered navigation I don't see any Color or Size from the associated products of configurable products,  neither it searches for the selected color or size in the associated child products of a configurable products. This has become a serious problem for me and it seems like this extension doesn't work with configurable products, I have already them too, but no reply as yet.

Has anyone went through the same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to re-index all. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is closed for noor. For the record the reason for misbehavior is in attribute setup  he had and in general is not related to SEO Layered Navigation Plus. What should be avoided:

Attributes used both in Layered Navigation should be allowed to set either on Configurable Product label or on simple product level. If you have not done it from the beginning, disabling attribute usage in configurable products is not enough as to that moment values can already be stored in database. So after disabling you should additionally delete values of that attribute assigned to all configurable products in catalog_product_entity_int table.